# The desktop on my third monitor is distorted

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 19.04

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 and on my third monitor on my second gpu the desktop is distorted. It is hard to explain what it looks like so here is a picture of it: https://i.imgur.com/wMjVql3.jpg

As you can see it the mouse is fine and is fine when I'm in Windows so it is not the monitor. Other windows i drag onto it also become distorted like this.

This was the second time I had to reinstall and the first time I didn't have this issue. But in the installer on both times It was like this.

My main GPU is a GTX 1050 which is running my two other monitors perfectly fine and the second is a GT 740 which is running the distorted monitor. The monitor(which really isn't a monitor just a tv) is a ELEFW195.

I'm not sure if there is already a post about this because it is a difficult problem to explain so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Comment: first welcome to the forum and second more info is needed to help you such as the driver version you are using as this is likely the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image it receives has lost sync, which suggests your PC is sending a signal at a resolution or a refresh frequency it is not designed to accept.

The latest 64-bit Linux driver which supports both the GT1050 and GT740 is [version 430.50](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/151568); suggest you make sure that's what you are using.

A [search at the TV manufacturer website](http://elementelectronics.com/?s=ELEFW195&post_type=product) shows no manual or product information, but there was some information at Amazon. It has a maximum resolution of 1280×720@60Hz, so make sure that's the resolution you have the GT740 set to use. If it is, then replace the HDMI cable.

UPDATE: Your issue was solved by selecting a different resolution than Amazon's information suggested; 1280x768@60Hz worked for you. Congratulations!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long but I gave up on this for a little bit. When I tried to install the drivers you provided the monitor stopped being detected at all. I changed the resolution to 1280x768@60Hz and that fixed the issue. Thanks.